# Why AudioManager.getRingerMode() return only 3 modes?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-vibration

According to the [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getRingerMode()),

> getRingerMode() returns the current ringtone mode, one of
>   RINGER_MODE_NORMAL, RINGER_MODE_SILENT, or RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE.

But there should be 4 modes, right?

Sound ON, Vibrate OFF: ***How can I know that the setting is this one?***
Sound ON, Vibrate ON: RINGER_MODE_NORMAL
Sound OFF, Vibrate OFF: RINGER_MODE_SILENT
Sound OFF, Vibrate ON: RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE

Please help me out. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the ringer method to RINGER_MODER_NORMAL (Sound and vibrate on) and separately set the vibrate setting to VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF(turn off vibrate completely) OR VIBRATE_SETTING_ONLY_SILENT.(Vibrate only if the mode is silent) as below:

To turn off ringtone vibrations:

```
setVibrateSetting (AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER,AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF)
```

To turn off notification vibrations:

```
setVibrateSetting (AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION,AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF)
```

UPDATE:To get the status of the current audio mode by

```
   if(getRingerMode ()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
    {    if((getVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER))==AudioManager.AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF){    
        Log.d("Ringer Mode is":"ring with no vibraion")
        }
    else{
    Log.d("Ringer Mode is":"ring with vibraion")
    }

    else if(getRingerMode ()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT){

if((getVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER))==AudioManager.AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF){    
        Log.d("Ringer Mode is":"Silent with no vibraion")
        }
    else{
    Log.d("Ringer Mode is":"Silent with vibraion")
    }
    }
else{
 Log.d("Ringer Mode is":"Silent with vibraion")

}
```

In the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_SILENT) it is said that it RINGER_MODE_SILENT mode will override the vibrate setting.

**PS**: According to DOC **get/setVibrateSetting()**method was **deprecated** in API level 16.
Note: I havent Tested the code.

Comment: I am not going to turn it off. Just need to know the system setting.

Comment: You can use the combitaion of  getRingerMode() and getVirateSetting() to get the effect you desire.

Comment: But getVirateSetting() is deprecated... "This method was deprecated in API level 16. Applications should maintain their own vibrate policy based on current ringer mode that can be queried via getRingerMode()."

Comment: Though the marked as deprecated the method is till availble,If you fear about portability I have just checked the source of lollipop the method is still available https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/media/java/android/media/AudioManager.java

Comment: Will deprecated functions ever be removed?  Is there any worry about future-proofing?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "vibrate_when_ringing", 0) == 1)
{    
    return true;
}
else if (Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "vibrate_when_ringing", 0) == 0)
{
    return false;
}
```

I have try, useful